# GPO uninstalled program instead of installing it

Tags: group-policy, msi

We have a couple computers that are having issues wherein every time they reboot, instead of installing a software by GPO, it instead removes it. The software works fine on most, but some of our newer ones (all of which are setup using WDS, and have the software pre-installed in the image) continue to have the issue. We have installed it manually, and even tried uninstalling it, but since it does network management, it requires a reboot afterwards, and this triggers the uninstall process. Nothing has changed, either in the image, the installer, or the GPO, in the last several months, and the problem has only just started occurring. Going through the even logs, we can see the MSIEXEC trigger when the software is installed, but it quits if it isn't. Does anyone have any ideas on how we could fix this on the few that don't have it, or is re-installing the OS the only option?

EDIT: Figured it out. Turns out that the permissions on the folder were set strangely, which wasn't causing an issue for most computers. I had to add the Authenticated Users group with Read and Execute permissions in order for the computer account to have access during boot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Turns out that the permissions on the folder were set strangely, which wasn't causing an issue for most computers. I had to add the Authenticated Users group with Read and Execute permissions in order for the computer account to have access during boot.

Answer (score 0):

Check the setting Uninstall Software if computer falls out of scope. If checked it will remove the software.

http://kb.mit.edu/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=15140184#WindowsServerPlatforms-IntroductiontoGroupPolicy-Specifyingsoftwareinstallationdefaults

Comment: The box isn't checked. I did a little bit of digging in RSOP, and discovered that there is an error regarding access the file. I'm working on digging deeper into it.

Comment: Figured it out. Turns out that the permissions on the folder were set strangely, which wasn't causing an issue for most computers. I had to add the Authenticated Users group with Read and Execute permissions in order for the computer account to have access during boot.

Comment: Excellent, Glad you found it and gives me something to keep in the back of my head if I ever come across this problem.